# Installing Qt5.1.1 and making it run with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt5, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to install Qt5.1.1 and have already installed VStudio 2010 Pro, but I stll get the error saying Qt needs a compiler set up to build.

I looked it up, and I only find very complex solutions that are impossible for me to implement.

Can anyone give me specific directions on how I can get Qt5.1.1 working in my laptop?

Btw in case you couldn't tell, I'm a newbie.

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure and build Qt from a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt? Did you install ActiveState Python and ActiveState Perl before you ran configure in the Qt sources?

Comment: Have you installed the right Qt libraries? I mean the Qt libraries built with Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, ensure that your Visual Studio installation contains a 32-bit compiler (the official Visual Studio 2010 packages only support 32-bit compilers)
2. Then, ensure that you've downloaded and installed one of the packages that are marked *"Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010)"* from http://qt-project.org/downloads
3. If Qt Creator still doesn't auto-detect your compiler, add it manually: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-tool-chains.html
4. If you had to add your compiler manually, also add a Kit to combine your compiler with your Qt libraries: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-targets.html

Comment: I was having trouble because I had the 64-bit. But I solved it by downloading the one that include MinGW compiler or w/e...that sovled the problem.
Thanks though, friend.